# PHP and sql diplay item

Tags: php, mysql

I'm facing some problem regarding to display data from sql.
I store my data into 2 table: table student and table company.

table student
{ id, name, company_code, fac_staff_id }

table company 
{id, company_name, company_state}

I'm trying to create a table shown as below.

- State A

  - company A

    - student 1
    - student 2
  - company B

    - student 3
    - student 4
- State B

  - company C

    - student 5
  - company D

    - student 6
    - student 7
    - student 8

I tried create a table similar as above structure but just want classify all the student based on there company_state. The output just display only one state and put all student into that state.

```
          $querysel = "SELECT DISTINCT c.company_state,s.fac_staff_id FROM tblcompany 
           c, tblstudent s WHERE c.id = s.company_code " ;
          $resultsel = mysql_query($querysel, $connection);
          $querystdsel = "SELECT s.name,c.company_state  FROM tblcompany c,
           tblstudent s WHERE c.id = s.company_code " ;
          $resultstdsel = mysql_query($querystdsel, $connection);

    while($rowsel =mysql_fetch_array($resultsel)){

    if ($rowsel['fac_staff_id'] == NULL){

    echo $rowsel['company_state'];

    while($rowstdsel =mysql_fetch_array($resultstdsel)){

    if($rowstdsel['company_state']=$rowsel['company_state']){

      echo $rowstdsel['name']; 

    }

    }

    }
      }
```

Hope someone can tell me way to create a table like above or any alternative ways because i'm still poor in php and mysql. thank you

Comment: Could you post valid PHP code, and indent it properly? `echo ['company_state']` is missing the variable name. And why do you have backticks around the `$` in the first 4 lines?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` for PHP MySQL! It's deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: sorry for making mistake while edit. basically the code still not complete and i'm trying to make the code can search for the company_state first then only group to company_name but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You should join your statements to have only one result, where every row looks like this with "order by company_state, company_name"

```
state | company | student
A  | A  | student1
A  | A | student2
A  | B | student3
....
```

In your php you then use lists to get your structure. Something like this: Just written down and no nice, clean, functional code!

```
<?php

$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo "<ul>";

$lastcompany = "";
$laststate = "";

foreach($rows as $row)
{
  if(($laststate == "") or ($laststate != $row['state']))
  {
    // New Item on mainlist: states

    if($laststate != $row['state'])
    { // close previous lists (students, companies)
      echo "</ul></ul></li>";
    }

    echo "<li>".$row['state'];    
  }


  if(($lastcompany == "") or ($lastcompany != $row['company']))
  {
    // New Item on mainlist: companies

    if($lastcompany != $row['company'])
    { // close previous (students) list
      echo "</ul></li>";
    }

    echo "<li>".$row['company'];    
  }

  // New student entry
   echo "<li>".$row['company']."</li>";


  // Redmine company and state for next iteration
  $lastcompany = $row['company'];
  $laststate = $row['state'];
}


// After all close all lists
echo "</ul></ul></ul>";

?>
```

Comment: actually i tried to use one statement query to do but it also bring me same result.
$querysel = "SELECT * FROM tblcompany 
           c, tblstudent s WHERE c.id = s.company_code " Or should i use JOIN?
Anyway, i will try to implement using the same method you using.

Comment: and actually i trying to make a table based on the structure where the  student will be group by state after that company name.